# uploading all data in a database row

Tags: php, sql, database

I'm trying to display all my table rows in an ordered fashion

`database table = u_visits`

`rows = id/ip_adress/visits/dates`

here is my code:

```
<html>
<body>
<?php

include 'includes/connect3.php';

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM u_visits");
$num = mysqli_num_rows($result);

?>
<table border="0" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="2">
<tr>
<td>
<font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">Value1</font>
</td>
<td>
<font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">Value2</font>
</td>
<td>
<font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">Value3</font>
</td>
<td>
<font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">Value4</font>
</td>
<td>
<font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">Value5</font>
</td>
</tr>
<?php
 $i=0;
 while ($i < $num) {
   $f1 = mysqli_result($result,$i,"id");
   $f2 = mysqli_result($result,$i,"ip_adress");
   $f3 = mysqli_result($result,$i,"visits");
   $f4 = mysqli_result($result,$i,"dates");
?>
<tr>
<td>
<font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><?php echo $f1; ?></font>
</td>
<td>
<font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><?php echo $f2; ?></font>
</td>
<td>
<font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><?php echo $f3; ?></font>
</td>
<td>
<font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><?php echo $f4; ?></font>
</td>
<td>
<font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><?php echo $f5; ?></font>
</td>
</tr>
<?php$i++;}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks in advance for all your help! 
If this is not the way to go about for what im trying to accomplish i am open to new suggestions Thanks again.

Comment: What is the problem? and why are you using `mysql_*` and `mysqli_*` in a same place?

Comment: @Console it just gives me a server problem and the mysql isnt in my file i copied and pasted an older version of my file

Comment: Can you paste the error message? Also put some space around here <?php $i++; } ?>

Answer (score 0):

Why do the ordering after you get the data? Why not ask the database to return the data already ordered.

`SELECT * id, ip_adress, visits, dates FROM u_visits ORDER BY id ASC`

This is the beauty of ORDER BY, give it a column index and a direction in which to order.